# how can i save the image and roi to train classifier

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, classification, matlab-cvst

i use this code

```
axes(handles.axes1)
h=imrect;

position = round(wait(h));

curImg=1;

I=imread(strcat(pathname, filename{k}));
[rows, columns, numberOfColorBands] = size(I);
% Crop image
I2 = imcrop(I,position);

figure;
imshow(I2);

 data(curImg).imageFilename = I;
 data(curImg).objectBoundingBoxes = position;
 curImg = curImg + 1;
```

i select roi than i extract the position and i save the pathname and the position of  the roi, when i use  the struct data to train classifier it dosen't work, here is the code:

```
trainCascadeObjectDetector('Detector.xml',data,negativeFolder,'FalseAlarmRate',0.2,'NumCascadeStages',5);
```

hope to get a response.

Answer (score 0):

Use `trainingImageLabeler` app to label your images. Then export the ROIs to your workspace, and pass them to `trainCascadeObjectDetector`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but i want the labeling in my GUI .